# F# recursive function with match pattern error

Tags: recursion, f#, pattern-matching, syntax-error

I have the following function that takes a real number and calculates its continued fraction.
However i have tried to make it using match but i don't know if its possible anymore  because i need to do the following check  `b < 0.0000000001` but i dont know how it can be done without an if-statement only using match, i need to be able to utilize the < operator

```
let rec floatfrac (x : float) : int list = 
    let a = int x
    let b = x - (float a)
    match b with
    | b < 0.0000000001 -> [] // error here because wrong syntax
    | _ -> (floatfrac (1.0 / b ))

printfn "%A" (floatfrac 3.14)
```

*error FS0010: Unexpected floating point literal in pattern. Expected infix operator, quote symbol or other token.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a match statement with a guard - that's where you can provide additional predicates for a value to fulfill that are not captured by the case pattern itself:

```
let rec floatfrac (x : float) : int list = 
    let a = int x
    let b = x - (float a)
    match b with
    | _ when b < 0.0000000001 -> [] 
    | _ -> (floatfrac (1.0 / b ))
```

But as you can see from the fact both cases use a wildcard, it's kind of pointless to use a match in the first place when a simple if would do:

```
if b < 0.0000000001 then 
    [] 
else 
    floatfrac (1.0 / b)
```